# Android application session management

Tags: android, session

I have to maintain statistics based on session in my application. Problem is that android never closes the application even when the user exits the application using the back button (might be because I'm running services in the background).

I would like to reset my session information if the application is in the background for say X minutes (to differentiate it from say a phone call or alarm). Is there any way to do that?

Maybe a some sort of a broadcast receiver to detect the event ... ?

Let me try to explain the scenario a little bit. There is this part of my application which can be accessed only after authentication (entering a password). Now once the user is inside this part, I wouldn't want to keep asking the user for authentication every time the activity is paused. But say the user presses the Home key and returns to the application after say, 20 minutes, I would like to ask for authentication.

EDIT : I am working with multiple activities, so I cannot detect the application going to the background simply setting a flag in the `onPause()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private static boolean isApplicationGoingToBackground(final Context context) {

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
            if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Call in onStop. onStop gets called after onStart of whatever takes over the screen - if its an activity in the same apk package then you're not going into the background. This does require the GET_TASKS permission, and if an activity comes up without you backing out it'll still trigger (user selects something from the notification bar or something).

Or bind to a service onStart & unbind onStop - the service will then be onDestroyed when all your activities are stopped (or track binds vs unbinds if you don't want to rely on onDestroyed getting called - because it might not..).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think your app does close when the user exists the app using the back button (unless you are catching it for something else or having other services running in the background that share the same session preference.

Anyways...

To answer your question, there two easy ways to do what you wanted to do:

1. Try [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html). It does the job really well. Or Google Analytics for mobile, they all pretty easy to use and they handle those for you.
2. If you want to do the background check simply record a SharedPreference in the onPause() block of the activity, refresh it when a new screen that is part of your app shows up, and at the same time checks if the old one has already expired (this will happen in the onResume()).

Comment: I could use Flurry/Google Analytics, but you see the information I am trying to reset is inside applciation, nothing to do with reporting/tracking.

Comment: I see you updated the question. onPause should work if you can accurately keep a record and detect it the right way. To keep it short, use a SharedPreference to keep the last active time and refresh it. If you can't set onPause(), that's fine, just set onResume() to check that time. That's always a valid case since it has to be bought to foreground. If you reallly don't trust that way, try using AlarmManager and refresh the alarm every time when theres an interaction and make the pending event to nullify the session. There are tons of ways to do this, but using preferences is very simple.

Comment: Keep in mind that it doesn't matter if you are working with multiple activities. If they are the same application running on the same process, there's usually a clear stack.